# Oracle server for reporting services?

Tags: oracle

Can anybody let me know what is "Oracle Reports 11g Release 1?"
Is this a server apart from Oracle Database server or this can be installed in the Oracle Database server itself?
I am looking for a reporting service in oracle. Ex. as we have SSRS in MSSQL. is there anything similar in Oracle??

Regards, 
R.R

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Reports is a licensed server that processes Reports templates (designed with Oracle Reports Designer). It is not easy to use and is quite expensive. Simple (free) reporting is best done with APEX, but it does not natively produce print quality reports. You can combine it with the free JasperReports (or BIRT) solutions for print quality output.